# Меню копирования/вставки в консоли пропало для готовому exe из Pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Всем привет! такой вопрос: сделал exe при помощи pyinstaller --onefile. все хорошо, но в работе скрипта надо вставить текст из буфера обмена. Но если нажать правой кнопкой мыши по окну- выпадающее меня со вставкой (как в cmd) не выходит. Выходит только если щелкнуть по верхней панели окна программы, что ОЧЕНЬ неудобно. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть решение этого вопроса?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотелось бы щелкнув на черном поле окна получить это меню с функцией Вставить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Выходит только если щелкнуть по верхней панели окна программы` а что выходит-то? Все равно нет действия для копирования/вставки

Comment: изменить-вставить есть

Comment: Ну, хз... а может тот текст не из буфера вставлять, а из файлика брать -- пусть скрипт по указанному пути откроет файлик и возьмет оттуда текст

Comment: можно, но нужно из буфера (для удобства)

Comment: покажите какое ожидаемое поведение без `pyinstaller --onefile`.

Comment: @jfs поправил вопрос

Comment: или если это возможно, кодом например по сочетанию клавиш вставлять из буфера текст

Comment: это выглядит как интерфейс консоли -- у вас консольное приложение, которое со стандартного ввода читает? Покажите полный пример скрипта (например: `import pyperclip; print(pyperclip.paste()[::-1])`) какой командой точно со всеми опциями его собирали, какие файлы конфигурации использовали. Упомяните версии ПО.

Comment: python 3.5.0, да приложение консольное, в самом начале приложение запрашивает строку через input (), в этот input и нужно вставить текст из буфера. из доп библиотек только requests. Можно написать текст вручную и все сработает, можно вставить щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши на верхней панели окна, тоже сработает. Но хочется не мучаться и вставлять по щелчку на черном поле окна консоли (как в  cmd). Или в скрипте прописать, при нажатии Ctrl-V вставлять из буфера

Comment: собирался скрипт командой pyinstaller --onefile script.py

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что меню появляется исчезает в одной и той же консоли в зависимости от того какую команду вы запускаете? К примеру, с  `py -c "input('> ')"` есть меню, но если `input('> ')` положить в i.py файл и собрать, используя `pyinstaller --onefile i.py`, то *в той же консоли* меню пропадёт? Версию Windows, pyinstaller укажите. Информацию необходимую для ответа, в сам вопрос помещайте. Нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Решил немного костылем, но все же: как писал @jfs сделал с помощью pyperclip

```
pyperclip.paste()
```